# Problem with NumericUpDown type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, numericupdown

When i do something like this:

```
public static void BindData<T>(this System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection controls, T bind)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            if (control.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox) || control.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)))
            {
                UtilityBindData(control, bind);
            }
            else
            {
                if (control.Controls.Count == 0)
                {
                    UtilityBindData(control, bind);
                }
                else
                {
                    control.Controls.BindData(bind);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void UtilityBindData<T>(Control control, T bind)
    {
        Type type = control.GetType();

        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("BindingProperty");
        if (propertyInfo == null)
            propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Tag");

// rest of the code....
```

where controls is `System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection` and among controls on the form that is passed as a parameter to this piece of code there are NumericUpDowns, i cant find them in the controls collection (controls=myForm.Controls), but there are controls of other types(updownbutton, updownedit). The problem is that i want to get NumericUpDown's Tag property and just cant get it when using that recursive method of checking form controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Tag` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) is defined by the `Control` class.

Therefore, you don't need reflection at all; you can simply write

```
object tag = control.Tag;
```

Your code isn't working because the control's actual type (eg, `NumericUpDown`) doesn't define a separate `Tag` property, and `GetProperty` doesn't search base class properties.

---

By the way, in your first `if` statemeant, you can simply write

```
if (control is TextBox)
```

Comment: Yes, but still control.Tag comes as null.

Comment: That means you didn't set it to anything.

Comment: i set numericupdown control's, that is located on the form, tag property to some value.. But in the loop there is no NumericUpDown controls..Instead there are UpDownButton and UpDownEdit. Thanks for the first "if" ;)

Comment: oops..read your edited answer..Will check now something else..Thank you

Comment: it helped! Added this: 
if (control.Controls.Count == 0 || (control is NumericUpDown))
                    {
                        UtilityBindData(control, bind);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        control.Controls.BindData(bind);
                    }

turns out that NumericUpDown is complex control that consists of several other base ones.